# Arduino input detection time

Tags: input, io, arduino

I was wondering, that if I could build a simple program on Arduino which would detect direction of sound. I would have 2 microphones connected to arduino and when sound is detected, arduino would tell which microphone reacted first.

I'm concerned about if arduino would be fast enough to detect this difference, since I would be using this device on metal pipes. Speed of sound in metal is ~5000m/s, so if microphones would be 1 meter away from each other, this would mean 0,2 millisecond difference.

Would arduino be able to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very doable. However, analog reads are not as fast as digital reads. If you spend too much time in between reads, a delay in one speaker could simply register as a slightly lower value, but at the same time.

However, looking at the datasheet, a single sample takes 13 clock cycles in free running mode which is about 812.5 ns so there is plenty of time to do multiple reads, possibly even more than 10 bit read. Just remember this is directly using an ADC, not using the Arduino `analogRead()` function which is far slower.

You could have a search and see if someone has posted some timings for `analogRead()`, however there are lots of tutorials for using the ADC directly.

Also, if you want instantaneous readings, you could redesign your circuit to give a digital pulse after the sensor detects above a threshold. Then using external interrupts, you can capture the first sensor triggered within 1 cycle of pulsing. Searching for threshold detector could point you in the right direction.